# What kind of privilege do we need to trace a process in linux

Tags: linux, security, kernel, posix, trace

It seems that we can trace other processes with trace functions? Operating system is obliged to provide such an  interface. Obviously we can obtain others data such as hidden password when they call a system call, it's a risk. Is there a mechanism to prevent the process from being traced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability under Linux. If you don't have it, you can only trace processes that you can send signals to, except those running set-user-ID/set-group-ID.
A process can also explicitely refuse to be ptraced, using  prctl() and setting the PR_SET_DUMPABLE flag.

See man ptrace(2) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can always hash the password because issuing the system call, I think. And I think you require a given amount of privilege to hook the login manager's API calls, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: There might need some privilege, but, I want to know what kind of privilege it is, the manuals are a little bit intricate.